# Sorting a file in-place in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

Using Python, I have a file in this format:

```
0.wav, stop 
1.wav, no 
10.wav, up 
100.wav, yes 
1000.wav, bed 
1001.wav, four 
1002.wav, three 
1003.wav, five 
1004.wav, nine 
1005.wav, go
```

I would like to sort it (in-place) by the number appearing in the wav file:

```
0.wav, stop 
1.wav, no 
2.wav, yes 
3.wav, house
```

I tried doing it by creating a list, appending to it all the lines of the file and then sorting it with a function as a key:

```
def sort_file(filename):
    sorted_file = filename
    file_list = list()
    with open(sorted_file) as fin:
        for line in fin:
            file_list.append(line.strip())
    # sort the list
    file_list.sort(key=sort_list_key)


def sort_list_key(file_list):
    for elem in file_list:
        my_key = elem.split(',')[0].split['.'][0]
        return my_key
```

But it didn't work.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the 2nd split function having [] instead of () and your sort_list_key method. I have provided a more comprehensive, simple working example with lambda.

```
file_content = ['0.wav, stop', 
                '1.wav, no', 
                '10.wav, up', 
                '100.wav, yes', 
                '1000.wav, bed', 
                '1001.wav, four', 
                '1002.wav, three', 
                '1003.wav, five', 
                '1004.wav, nine', 
                '1005.wav, go' ]

file_content.sort(key = lambda f: f.split(',')[0].split('.')[0], reverse=False)
print(file_content)
```